# Typescript class: Why does this compile?

Tags: typescript

I want to write a class like this:

```
class Foo {
    public someProp = '123';
}
```

but I mistyped and wrote this:

```
class Foo{
    public someProp: '123'; // not "="
}
```

I expect getting a compilation error but nothing happens. Why is it so?

Comment: Why *would* you get a compile error? You can use this behaviour to create a string equivalent of enums (otherwise not supported pre-2.4): `direction: 'left' | 'right';`. See [string literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know there is string literal types.

Comment: Works with any type not just strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because TypeScript supports constatnts as type when you need to list allowed values in the field. It is not a bug. It is feature. :)

```
var x: '123';
var y: '123' | '456';

x = '123';
x = '456'; // Error
x = '789'; // Error

y = '123';
y = '456';
y = '789'; // Error
```

see [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20x%3A%20'123'%3B%0D%0Avar%20y%3A%20'123'%20%7C%20'456'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ax%20%3D%20'123'%3B%0D%0Ax%20%3D%20'456'%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0Ax%20%3D%20'789'%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%0D%0Ay%20%3D%20'123'%3B%0D%0Ay%20%3D%20'456'%3B%0D%0Ay%20%3D%20'789'%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A)